# Downstream switch intermittently not connecting to router

Tags: networking, router, switch

In my home I've got a router which is connected to a managed TL-SG1016PE 16 port switch which is providing connectivity to the house. From the switch i have wired 2 accesspoints for wifi and wired 4 rooms with wall LAN connection. The switch configuration is running default settings.

In my office room I have 2 computers and only 1 wall LAN connection, so I have wired the wall LAN connection to a secondary unmanaged switch TP LS1005G 5 port. So in my office the connection is Router->main switch->secondary switch->2 wired computers

In my office I seem to get issues where i loose connectivity back to the router intermittently from both computers. A continuous ping to the router IP will sometimes timeout and reestablish itself, and other times completely fail. When it completely fails it is not possible to reach the router anymore. A restart of the switch will work temporarily until the problem occurs again.

If I disconnect 1 of the computers on the secondary switch in the office there are no issues.The problem only occurs when there are more than 1 computer in the secondary switch.

Thinking the secondary switch was faulty, I replaced with a new switch of the same model, and it has the same pattern = intermittent lost connection to router.

When the problem occurs, and I try a "ipconfig /renew" I get the following error: "An error occurred while renewing interface Ethernet : unable to contact your DHCP server. Request has timed out."

I'm puzzled to what I am doing wrong, as having a downstream switch to another switch should be normal scenario. And since the switch works through the connected MAC addresses, it shouldn't be possible to have IP conflicts.

Suggestions on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Do you know for sure that it isn't an IP conflict?

Comment: Difficult to say, I cannot find anywhere on the vendor's website or in the manual that the switch should operate on layer 3, so assuming layer 2 switch, it doesn't operate on IP addresses but on mac addresses and ports. Assuming I am wrong, how would I detect this? Check the ip address assigned to both computers when the issue occurs?

Comment: The switch doesn't operate on IP addresses, but the computers connected to it do. If they're the ones losing connectivity, do they have duplicate IP addresses? The switch is practically "transparent" to IP – it can neither cause nor prevent anything IP-related.

Comment: Update: When the error occured, and I lost all connectivity, I could confirm that PC1 and PC2 on the 5 port switch had different IP addresses, so it is not an IP conflict.

Answer (score 0):

I use these TPLink switches myself in several deployments and they are normally quite solid.
As you stated replacing the 5-port didn't help...

So that leads me to the conclusion it is either in the cabling or in those 2 PC's.

If it is caused by one of the PC's itself you should be able to determine that by operating only 1 PC on that 5-port switch for a while. Please note with only one PC it can potentially take significantly LONGER to trigger the issue. Maybe 5 to 10 times longer.

And check your patch cables (get 1 extra cable and swap each existing one for the new one for a couple of hours to see if the problem goes away).
Don't forget he problem could be on the side of the 16-port switch in stead of the room were the 5-port is, so check the patch-cable on the 16-port switch side too.
Also make sure that the connection between the 2 switches is actually Gigabit. If it drops to 100 mb/s the PC's can easily overload the 5-port, which may not recover from that without a reboot. (Check the switch leds ON BOTH switches to see if you get Gigabit on both ends. If only 1 end shows gigabit and the other shows 100 mb/s you have a mis-wire or bad contact in one of the outlets.

Last but not least...
It would be quite rare, but it isn't unheard off.
When you replaced the 5-port switch did you also replace the power-supply or did you just plug-in the replacement on the existing power-supply as it was a like-for-like replacement?
If the power-supply is flaky it may be able to drive the switch with one PC connected all day long, but the slightly higher power-draw with a second PC on the switch might just be enough to cause stability issues like the one you describe.

Comment: Good points, thanks!

I tried running both PC's individually on the 5 port switch for multiple days, and neither had any issues. The issue only occurs when both PCs are connected to the 5 port switch.

As both PC's have run their own patch cable during individual testing from the 5 port switch to the PC, I guess that rules out the patch cables in the 5 port switch->PC, 5 port switch->to the wall outlet and router->16 port switch and 16-port-switch->wall outlet .

Comment: The 16 port switch shows gigabit connection, the 5 port does not indicate gigabit vs megabit (both are just light on, and the light is on)

And I did reuse the power supply . I’ve replaced that now to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Update: New power supply still gave error.